# SwiftUI iOS - Searchable with TabView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is anyone having problems using .searchable inside a TabView?
Before I implemented the TabView it was working just fine, and it is still showing on the preview.

This is the code now (does not show the search bar):

```
var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                List(searchResults, children: \.items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: CarView(carData: carData).onAppear() {
                        carData.selectedCar = item.pageId
                        Task {
                            await carData.fetchCarData()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("\(item.name)")
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
                    .fontDesign(.monospaced)
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Models", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }
            AIView(classifier: classifier)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("AI", systemImage: "camera.metering.multispot")
                }
            InfoView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Info", systemImage: "info.square")
                }
        }
        .tint(.darkBackground)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
```

So I tried multiple forms of implementing the search bar and none worked well, some of options really broke the tabview or the bar was always visible in any view with broken animations.

This is the code before where the search bar was working as intended (showing when the list is pulled).

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(searchResults, children: \.items) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: CarView(carData: carData).onAppear() {
                    carData.selectedCar = item.pageId
                    Task {
                        await carData.fetchCarData()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("\(item.name)")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Models", displayMode: .inline)
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .automatic))
        }
    }
```

[This is the preview which shows the search bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8yP0.png)